# Resize iframe to fit content, then use jquery

Tags: jquery, css, iframe, resize, height

I am using the following code to resize the iframe dynamically using jquery. HTML pages load inside it, and all have different heights.

The problem: If a link is clicked, the iframe height is set - so when a second link is hit the iframe uses the height of the previous html first, then shrinks to fit the content of the current one. So I suppose I have to "reset" the function each time a link is clicked. How can I do that?

P.S: On this http://jsfiddle.net/UWqSb/3/ it doesn't work(shrinks down), although on my page the content loads and animates correctly.

resize iframe dynamically and animate

```
$("#targetIframe").load(function() {
    $("#targetIframe").animate({ height:( $("#targetIframe").contents().find("body").height())  },500);
});
```

animate the div container using jquery and also close div when button is clicked

```
$("#targetIframe").ready(function() {
        // cache elements
        var $targetDiv = $("#targetContent"),
            $iframe = $targetDiv.find("#targetIframe"),
            $close = $targetDiv.find("#myClose");

        // bind click events to first link and close button
        $(".iframe").on("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault(); 
            $iframe.attr({
                "src": this.href // add the content to iframe before showing
            }).parent($targetDiv).slideDown(500, function () { $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$("#portfolio").offset().top}, 500); //show div
                $close.fadeIn(200).on("click", function () { 
                    $(this).fadeOut(100, function () { // fade out close button
                        $targetDiv.slideUp(500, function () { // hid div by sliding it up
                            //$iframe.removeAttr("src"); // remove after closing the box
                        }); // slideUp
                    }); // close fadeOut                
                }); // on click myClose
            }); // slideDown
        }); // on click link
    }); // ready
```